# Check to see if text is contained within a variable in a list in Python

Tags: python, list

I am working with this code:

```
test_list = ['small_cat', 'big_dog', 'turtle']

if 'dog' not in test_list:
    output = 'Good'
else:
    output = 'Bad'

print (Output)
```

Because 'dog' is not in the list, 'output' will come back with a response of 'Good'.  However, I am looking for 'output' to return 'Bad' because the word 'dog' is part of an item in the list.  How would I go about doing this?

Comment: `if not any('dog' in word for word in test_list)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should iterate all the values in `test_list` -

```
output = 'Good'
for test_word in test_list:
    if 'dog' in test_word:
        output = 'Bad'
        break

print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to check each one in the list:

```
output = 'Good'
for item in test_list:
    if 'dog' in item:
        output = 'Bad'
print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

`any` and `all` are super useful for this combined with a generator expression.

```
if any('dog' in w for w in test_list):
  ...
else:
  ...
```

Both `any` and `all` are very expressive of what they're doing, and they short-circuit: as soon as the outcome is known, they stop iterating. They can be combined with conditional expressions to permit:

```
output = "Bad" if any('dog' in w for w in test_list) else "Good"
```